# C++ vector of fixed size vecors

Tags: c++, stl

How can I declare vector of fixed size vectors in C++?

For example:

`vector of vectors with N elements.`

Not this:

```
vector<vector<int> > v(N) //declares vector of N vectors
```

Comment: Does the "fixed size vector" have to be a `std::vector`?

Comment: Use std::array<type, size>

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: As you can see from all the answers, you can't do what you want to do. `std::vector<std::array<int, N>>` is your best alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

std::array is your friend here.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

For instance, to declare vector of vectors with N elements, you can

```
typedef std::array<int, N> N_array;
```

Then use

```
std::vector<N_array>
```

Comment: Note that std::array is C++11. If you are stuck with C++03, use [Boost.Array](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/array.html).

Comment: There is no need to typedef. `std::vector<std::array<int, N>>` is perfectly fine (in C++03 requires space between the closing angle brackets, but C++11 will understand them without one and so will even pre-c++11 versions of visual C++)

Comment: @JanHudec, you are perfectly right. Typedef here is just to make the syntax slightly simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could use std::array:

```
std::array<int, 10>    myNumbers;
```

The only down side to this is you can't see how many "active" elements there are, since you don't push/emplace back. You use it like an ordinary( but safe ) array.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have `vector` of fixed size, most likely you don't need one! Use `std::array` instead.

But still you insist to have one..

```
vector<vector<int> > vecOfVec(NumberOfVectors);
for ( int i = 0 ; i < NumberOfVectors; i++ )
   vecOfVec[i].resize(NumberOfElementsInVector);
```

Comment: std::array requires knowing the number of elements at compile time. This is often not the case.